# run to all scripts with just one file ROS

Tags: ros

Hey I made a autonomous car ROS project. I have some scripts such as object detection and lane detection. How can I run these scripts with just one file. Are these should be .sh file or .launch file?

Answer (score 0):

If they’re all ros nodes they should be launched via roslaunch. [More documentation can be found here.](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) You should only be using shell scripts for things outside of the direct ROS ecosystem. For example, if you wanted to actually run the roslaunch commands when a computer boots up; e.g. through systemd.

Comment: it is work but when I add python3 file it shows me an error:                                          `[ZED][Init] [ERROR] Cannot load SVO file. Check that the path of the SVO is correct, avoid white spaces in filename, add ".svo" extension to filename.
INVALID SVO FILE
[levhaSerit-6] process has died [pid 18295, exit code 1, cmd /home/oret/oret_ws/src/oretotonom/levhaserit.py __name:=levhaSerit __log:=/home/oret/.ros/log/90fa2dec-0138-11ed-84a7-02425fca5e5a/levhaSerit-6.log].
log file: /home/oret/.ros/log/90fa2dec-0138-11ed-84a7-02425fca5e5a/levhaSerit-6*.log
`

Comment: @gurselturkeri as the error suggests you’re passing in an incorrect file path